# Ball and addition

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a this problem I'm trying prove, but I don't understand the addition notion in it.

$A$ is a closed subspace of a normed space. Prove that if $x\in A+B(0,\beta)$ for all $\beta>0$ then $x\in A$.

I know that $B(0,r)+\{a\}=B(a,r)$ but how is defined $B(0,r)+A$?

Comment: REr, your question is very easy to answer, as you can see the below answer  provided by Farnight. Notice, the assumption  of  being subspace on $A$ is redundant! So I think the question was something else. I suggest you to think about the following question.
\\

Let $A$ be a closed subspace and $B$ is a compact subset of vector space $X$. Assume $$ B  \cap  ( A +  B(0,a) )  \neq \emptyset $$ for all $ a  \ >  0  .$ then  $   B  \cap  A \neq \emptyset .$


the proof  of this question is  more  challenging when do not use  Hahn-Banach separation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the addition of two sets in vector spaces refers their Minokowski addition, i.e,     $A+B = \{ a + b :~ a \in A ,~ b \in B  \}. $

Answer (score 2):

Let $\beta>0$:

$$x\in A+B(0,\beta) \implies \exists a\in A \text{, } b\in B(0,\beta) \text{ such that }x=a+b$$

This means that $$||x-a||<\beta$$

Then $$B(x,\beta)\cap A \neq \varnothing$$

Therefore, $x\in \bar A$

Since $A$ is closed, $\bar A = A$

Then $x\in A$

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was an open or a closed ball. The result is correct in either case, anyway. But I'll clean it a little.

Comment: Oh, that's right. Sorry about that. It's fixed, now.